# rank $k$ matrices are connected

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, connectedness

Let $m,n$ be positive integers and $0\leq k\leq \min\{m,n\}$ an integer.

Prove or disprove that the subspace of $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ consisting of all matrices of rank equal to $k$ is connected.

Frankly, I have no idea how to even start this...

I guess this is not path connected atleast...

**Please give only hints**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A matrix $A$ has rank $k$ if and only if it is equivalent to the rank $k$ canonical matrix, ie
$$A=Q^{-1}BP$$
with
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
I_k & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
From this, try to prove that the space of rank $k$ matrices is path-connected.

Comment: Ok.. I think i got it... Here it is : Let $M$ and $N$ be two rank $k$ matrices.. Then we have invertibe matrices $C,D,P,Q$ such that $M=CBD$ and $N=PBQ$.. Then, as set of all invertble matrices are connected we have a path from $C$ to $P$ and a path from $D$ to $Q$.. So, we have a path from M$ to $N$.. Is this sufficient justification?

Comment: Yes this is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the step i would follow :

1. Show that you can restrict yourself to $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ if $n \leq m$
2. Show that $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is connected. (or use it if you already know that)
3. Show that the space of matrices having rank $k$ in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$  is the image of $GL_n(\mathbb{C}) \times GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ by a continuous and surjective application. (Using the hint augustin has given and the rank-nullity theroem)

Comment: If $n\leq m$ then rank of $A$ will be less than or equal to $n$ i.e., $A=\begin{bmatrix}B&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ where $B$ is a $n\times n $ matirx...

Comment: Connectedness of Gl is true only when $n\geq 2$.. What am i supposed to do in case of $n=1$?

Comment: I will think about it.

Comment: I do not understand... I said If $n\leq m$ then rank of $A$ will be less than or equal to $n$ i.e., $A=\begin{bmatrix}B&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ where $B$ is a $n\times n $ matirx... Is this correct

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: And $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is connected even for $n=1$. (because it is path-connected, you can join two complex numbers without going through 0)

Comment: Ok Ok... I was thinking about case of real numbers..