# Show that the set of $m\times n$ matrices with full rank is connected

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, connectedness

A subset $S\subset X$ is connected if for every $x$ and $y$ in $S$, there exists a continuous curve $r:[0,1]\rightarrow S$ such that $r(0)=x$ and $r(1)=y$.

I want to show that the set of all $m\times n$ matrices with $m>n$ with rank $n$ is connected.

[This](https://mountainscholar.org/bitstream/handle/20.500.11919/1578/FACW_MATH_1994_10886826_Evard_Jafari.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) paper shows that the set of all $m\times n$ matrices with $m>n$ with rank $n$ is connected by analytic regular arcs, which is more than what I need. I am struggling to follow all the arguments presented in the paper. I image that if the analytic arc part is removed, then the argument becomes much easier, but I am not sure.

The argument I was thinking is as follows: Let $V=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis, then all full rank matrices can be generated by placing the vectors $v_1,...,v_n$ into a matrix with some scalar factor distinct than $0$, namely, $[a_1v_1,a_2v_2,...,a_nv_n]$ (the only restriction for the $a_i$ is that they are nonzero). If we have two full rank matrices given by $m=[a_1v_1,a_2v_2,...,a_nv_n]$ and $n=[b_1v_1,b_2v_2,...,b_nv_n]$, then the curve $r$ is $r(\lambda)=(1-\lambda) m+\lambda n$ is clearly continuous and $r(0)=m$ and $r(1)=n$.

I don't think this argument is enough though. For example, if $n=-m$ then $r(0.5)=0$ which is outside of $S$.

Does anyone know how to show only the result I want? or is the analytic arc part unavoidable to show the connectedness?

Comment: There are several flaws in your argument. First, $m$ and $n$ must be positive integers since they determine the number of rows and columns of a given matrix. Second, why do you think that all matrices can be written by only one orthonormal set? If that were the case, all $n \times n$ matrices would be diagonal matrices by choosing the standard orthonormal basis. You can have change of basis matrix which takes any orthonormal basis to the given orthonormal basis. But you will also have to consider that in the final path that you construct.

Comment: See if these help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678257/rank-k-matrices-are-connected; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862992/connected-components-of-real-matrices-in-m-n-mathbb-r-with-constant-rank-k?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: By the way, that’s not the usual definition of “connected”. The definition you gave is the definition of “path-connected”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true more generally for matrices of rank $r$, where $ 0\leq  r\le \min(m,n)$.

I am assuming here that the matrices have real entries.

**Theoritical proof.**

Two rectangular matrices $M_1,M_2$ of same size $m\times n$ have same rank if and only if there exist two invertible matrices $U,V$ of appropriate sizes such that $M_2=UM_1V$.

**Notation.** if $\varepsilon\in\{\pm\}$, let $ GL_k^{\varepsilon}(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of $k\times k$ matrices whose determinant has sign $\varepsilon$.

Let $\varepsilon$ be the sign of $\det(U)$, and let $\varepsilon'$ be the sign of $\det(V)$.

The map $f:(U,V)\in GL_m^{\varepsilon}(\mathbb{R})\times GL_n^{\varepsilon'}(\mathbb{R})\mapsto UM_1V\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is continuous, and its image contains $M_1$ and $M_2$ by choice of $U$ and $V$.

Now  $ GL_m^{\varepsilon}(\mathbb{R})\times GL_n^{\varepsilon'}(\mathbb{R})$ is (path) connected, since it is the product of two (path) connected spaces, so the image of $f$ is (path) connected. In particular, you can join $M_1$ and $M_2$ by a continuous curve lying in the space of matrices of rank $r$.

**If you  want a more explicit version of the proof.** You need first to prove that $GL_k^\varepsilon (\mathbb{R})$ is path connected. For it is enough to prove that $GL_k^+ (\mathbb{R})$ is path connected (since any element of $GL_k^- (\mathbb{R})$ maybe written as $D_{-1}P$, where $D_{-1}=diag(1,\ldots,1,-1)$ and $P\in GL_k^+(\mathbb{R}))$.

Now, it is enough to show that you can connect an invertible matrix $P$ of positive determinant with the identity matrix $I_k$ using a path on $GL_k^+(\mathbb{R})$.
Let $\lambda=\det(P)>0$, so that $P=D_\lambda Q$, where $D_\lambda=diag (1,\ldots,1,\lambda)$, and $\det(Q)=1$.

Since $Q$ has determinant $1$, it is a product of transvection matrices. Hence, it is enough to convince ourselves that:

- we can connect $I_k$ and $D_\lambda$ using a path on $GL_k^+(\mathbb{R})$.
- we can connect $I_k$ and a transvection matrix using a path on $GL_k^+(\mathbb{R})$.

Both statements are obvious: for the first one, take $t\in [0,1]\mapsto diag (1,\ldots, 1, (1-t)+t\lambda)$, and for the second one, if $T=I_k+c E_{ij}$ is a transvection matrix, take $t\in [0,1]\mapsto I_k+ c tE_{ij}$.

Now to conclude the explicit argument, take a path $r:[0,1]\to GL_m^{\varepsilon}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $r(0)=I_m$  and $r(1)=U$, and a path $s:[0,1]\to GL_n^{\varepsilon'}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $s(0)=I_n$ and $s(1)=V$.

Then $\rho: t\in [0,1]\mapsto r(t)M_1s(t)\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is a path such that $\rho(0)=M_1$ and $\rho(1)=M_2$, whose image consists of matrices of rank $r$, since $r(t)$ and $s(t)$ are invertible for all $t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I just have one more question. You write $P=D_{\lambda}Q$, and then you just have that $I_k$ is path connected to $D_{\lambda}$ and $I_k$ is path connected to $Q$. How does that imply that $I_k$ is connected to $P$? I know that might be obvious, but it isn't to me. I am just trying to be rigorous.

Comment: If $r_i$ connects $I_k$ to $P_i$, then $r_1(t)...r_s(t)$ connects $I_k...I_k=I_k$ to $P_1...P_s$

Comment: That is my question though. It is not obvious to me why $r_i$ connects $I_k$ to $P_i$. I know you can connect $I_k$ to $D_\lambda$ and $I_k$ to the transvection matrix. I assume that implies that $I_k$ is connected to $P$, but that fact is not obvious to me.

Comment: Each $P_i$ is supposed to be $D_\lambda$ or a transvection matrix. If you know how to connect $I_k$ to $D_\lambda$ or a transvection matrix, then the formula above tells you you can connect $I_k$ to a product of such matrices. Since $Q$ (with the notation in my answer) is a product of transvection matrices ans $P=D_\lambda Q$...

Comment: $D_\lambda$ or a trasnvection matrix? I thought $P_i=D_\lambda Q$ was the product of $D_\lambda$ with a transvection matrix.