# Show that a matrices space is connected

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, connectedness

Prove that $2\times2$ complex matrices of determinant 0 and non null trace is connected.

What I did:

My intuition is that such matrices are similar to \begin{pmatrix}
z & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} with $z\ne 0$

So $E$ is isomorphic to $GL_2(\Bbb C) \times \Bbb C^*$ therefore $E$ is connected.

Is that correct?

Comment: What about $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$? It's not of that form.

Comment: indeed! I couldn't prove that matrices in E space are diagonalizable, since they're not hermitian nor unitary. However your matrix is diagonalizable so it is similar to a diagonal matrix in the form I suggested ?

Comment: Thus another way to describe your matrices is that they are rank one. Use the general result given for rank-$k$ matrices : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1678257

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb{C}$. a matrix is similar to a triangular matrix. Therefore here, all matrices are similar to 
\begin{pmatrix}
z & 1\\
0 & x
\end{pmatrix} with $z,x \in \mathbb{C}$.

The determinant is zero but not the trace, so the matrix is similar to
\begin{pmatrix}
z & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} with $z\ne 0$.

It characteristic polynomial is :
$P(T) = T(T-z)$
It has two differents roots so your matrix is diagonalizable... and similar to 
\begin{pmatrix}
z & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} with $z\ne 0$

Comment: Little remark :"matrice" (french) $\to$ "matrix" (english). Plural :"matrices" as well in french and in english.